# Программа нажатия кнопки через заданное время

Tags: c#

Нужна программа, которая будет автоматически вызывать нажатие кнопки "f10" через заданное мною время (не периодически) для реакции другой запущенной программы. Запросы в Google результата не дали.

Как новичку, стало интересно, можно ли написать что-то подобное, например, на C# без больших затрат времени? Есть идеи?

UPD: Насчёт `Timer` я понял. А как можно вызвать нажатие хоткея в методе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй `Timer`. Создаешь таймер и подписываешься на событие его срабатывания. В обработчике события вызываешь событие нажатой кнопки.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?